# Change logo svg color on scroll in Elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, filter, frontend, elementor

I need to change the color of the logo in elementor using a filter

In theory it should be like this, but it doesn't work

```
selector .elementor-widget-image{
    filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(100%) sepia(30%) saturate(2%) hue-rotate(268deg) brightness(113%) contrast(100%);
}

selector .elementor-sticky--effects >.elementor-widget-image {
   filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(0%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(85deg) brightness(104%) contrast(104%);
}
```